# Schedule Tweets PHP and Cron

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, twitter, cron

I am building a twitter application where a user can enter a tweet and can schedule it to be posted once, daily, weekly, or monthly. What is the best way to implement a cron job for this action? I can only think of running a cron job every minute and matching up the times and dates - this can't be the best solution as it would place a lot of stress on the server. I am running a lamp stack with ubuntu - any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: "Lot of stress"? If your cron-script is not *enormous*, the approach you describe will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cronjob that is executed every minute is perhaps a bit of overkill if the lowest interval is once a day. On the other hand, a script that does a query every minute isn't that much of a strain on a webserver as it probably can handle 1000 queries a minute on a relative low end server.

When your appliaction/website wil be used a lot you could starting about more optimalisation, but when your website/application gets that big, it is probably needed to run it every minute :).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using crontab, you'll need to create crontab entry for each variation of scheduling options (daily, weekly, monthly).  The script run for each entry would need to perform the work for all users opted into that scheduling frequency.

Crontab files follow a general format.  From the [crontab(5) man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/):

> ```
>        field         allowed values
>        -----         --------------
>        minute        0-59
>        hour          0-23
>        day of month  1-31
>        month         1-12 (or names, see below)
>        day of week   0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
> ```

- Daily would be:   `0 0 * * *`
- Weekly would be:  `0 0 * * 0`
- Monthly would be: `0 0 1 * *`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how it could be done, but there is this command in unix which could be used : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29